# Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Inspiron 5491 2 in 1, does it work?

Tags: dell, 20.04, inspiron

I'm looking to buy a Inspiron 5491 with i7, 8GB, 2 in 1 configuration. I'm currently using my old MacBook Pro (2012) and switching to Ubuntu. So my plan is to wipe Windows 10 and go full Ubuntu Focal Fossa. I have read problems with the Inspiron 5491 like no audio and WiFi problems witch probably will be fixed on a full install. My concern is that I pay 1000 euros and end op with a laptop that doesn't have a functional audio jack. I asked Dell if I can return the laptop within their returnpolicy (14 days) if I install Ubuntu alongside or on an external disk. I asked 2 times (diffrent employees) and both times they said no. Not sure what to do now. I searched all the internet for the last couple of weeks and can't find anything with the newest Ubuntu.

**My main question is: will Ubuntu 20.04 work properly (minor tweaks are fine) on the Inspiron 5491**

If there are some alternative 2 in 1 options, pleas let me know.
I need an Ubuntu laptop with

- at least 2 usb A ports (not trough a c hub)
- SD-card reader
- HDMI and DP (trough a c hub is fine, need docking with 2 screens attached)
- a 14 or 15 inch screen
- a keyboard with **no** num-pad so the track-pad will be in the middle
- 10th gen i7
- 2 in 1 convertible
- Upgradable memory to at least 16gb but 32 would be nice
- Intel integrated graphics is fine, an nvidia battery friendly is okay too

Yes, I know there are special Ubuntu,Manjaro,System76 laptop options, and I know my list is pretty long, but I think I found my laptop with the Dell Inspiron 5000 2 in 1 series

PS: new to this forum, hope I'm doing okay and thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't test it because I haven't ordered it yet. And if I do order it and test it out, I need to change some BIOS settings and break the Dell return-policy. I know a lot about installing Ubuntu on laptops and PC's and have done it very often so I know about tweaking and getting drivers trough terminal. But I saw some posts about audio that doesn't work (only if you leave the headphone plugged in all the time and it is much lower volume than it should be). Now fixes seen. Hoped someone out here has this laptop and can tell me if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 is only out a few months, there won't be a laptop or desktop in the whole world that it 100% works on yet. There will be little things, like the headphones sound problem on some devices, which you mentioned, for the next few months.

Dell are selling a lot of their new computers with Ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed again now, which means there will be good compatibility across models, even though the type you want doesn't specifically come with Ubuntu.

The only bios setting you need to change to test out Ubuntu on a live disk would be the boot order, that won't break your return-policy (as far as I know... that would be very odd). With the live-disk you'll be able to check that everything works (and that the things you find that might not work have fixes already.) without installing it or making any changes to your computer or hard drive.

I returned a Dell 4 years ago that had a faulty keyboard, it was dual-booted with Ubuntu and they had zero problems, asked zero questions, gave me my money back That maybe be different because it was a problem that they had caused, not me, EU law says any manufacturing fault makes something returnable for 2 whole years. You could always do a clean windows reinstall before returning it. 
So yeah, I think that as Piot said, this does apply to you:
[Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)